# How to add a subview that contains an iAd Banner View?

Tags: ios, xcode, iad, addsubview

I have a tab bar with 3 view controllers and I want to implement iAds to the app.

I have been searching and I read that a good way to implement the iAds is to create them apart, like in another ViewController, so that's what I did. I have my First, Second and ThirdViewController and an AdBannerController. I got the Bees 4 Honey iAd tutorial (http://bees4honey.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-add-iad-banner-in-iphoneipad-app/) and put the iAd in this view controller (AdBannerController). So, now I think I have to add a sub view to each ViewController (First, second and third), but I don't know how. I would be really thankful if you can help me (and if you know a better way to implement the iAds to a tabbar app, thanks a lot too!).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the TabbedBanner project in the Apple [iAdSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) sample?